# Get multidimensional sub array count in php

Tags: php

I have below type of array, now I want to get count of it's subarray

For example I want to get count key 7 & 8. How to do it ? Any solution for that ? I tried but but no success :(

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [Blogdata] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [blog_id] => 105

                                )
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [blog_id] => 101
                                )
                    )

                )

        )

)


$date_count = array(); 
foreach($FeaturedBlogs as $Key=>$date) {
     foreach($date as $d) {
        $key = array_keys($d);  // get our date
        // echo $key;echo "<br>";
        print_r($d);
        $date_count[$key[0]]++;
     }
}
```

Comment: *'I have below type of array'* You have an object. How is it generated?

Comment: i add my code here lease check

Comment: any solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you show your expected output as I'm still not sure.

Comment: you array is  stdClass Object. is it decoded from json?

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
//Count Sub Array
$final_array = [];
$x = 0;
function countSubArray($data)
{
    global $final_array;
    global $x;
    foreach($data as $key)
    {
        if(is_array($key))
        {
            $final_array[$x][0] = "1";
            $final_array[$x][1] = json_encode($key);
            $final_array[$x][2] = count((array)$key);
            $x++;
            countSubArray($key);
        }
        if(is_object($key))
        {
            $final_array[$x][0] = "2";
            $final_array[$x][1] = json_encode($key);
            $final_array[$x][2] = count((array)$key);
            $x++;
            countSubArray($key);
        }
    }

}

// Call Function...
countSubArray($arr);  // what array you count..

// Display Sub Array Count...
$t_count = 0;
foreach($final_array as $d)
{
    if($d[0] == 1)
    {
        echo "Array Count :".$d[2]." Array : ".$d[1]."<br>";
        $t_count++;
    }
}

echo "Total Array Count :".$t_count;
```

output of this example is...

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [Blogdata] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [blog_id] => 135
                                )

                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [blog_id] => 101
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
Array Count :1 Array : [{"blog_id":135}]
Array Count :1 Array : [{"blog_id":101}]
Total Array Count :2
```

Comment: This is not practical as you are hard coding the data.  I'm sure he is getting data that is changing all the time.

Comment: declaring stdClass Object elements are always default element names so i use $r->Blogdata  for count purpose...

Comment: The OP did not state that he was only after the arrays in the `Blogdata` object.  If that is the case then that would have actually made things easier.  However, that being said you code does not work.  What if the array has 100 elements?  What if the `Blogsdata` has more subarrays in it.

Comment: countSubArray() function counts the sub array elements even if the array has 100 elements or higher..

Comment: You count is going to be off because you are counting both objects and arrays.  Also you are not actually counting anything..  Your just echoing out the count of the array.

Comment: this example consists of normal arrays and object arrays. countSubArray() tracks both arrays and object arrays and its count and records it in an array. In your Answer, you did not initialize "count" variable in arrayCounter function. It may produce some warnings...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188093/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-balamurugan).

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

This is going to use a function as it's own callback function.  The function will loop through an object or an array and test each element to see if it is another object or array.

If it did find a new object or array, then the function calls itself again to perform the same operations on the element, effectively traversing through your entire array.

When it has found the bottom of each element it will return the value of the counter which was keeping track of how many arrays it came across.

Like so:

```
function arrayCounter($data){

  //At this point we have an array or an object.
  //Lets loop across the elements and see if we have any more nested arrays or objects.
  foreach($data as $key){

    $count = 0;        

    //Test each element to see if it's an object or an array.
    if(is_array($key) || is_object($key)){

      //If it is we are going to send the element through another instance of the function.
      $count += arrayCounter($key);

    }

    //If the element is an array we are going to increment the counter.
    if(is_array($key)){

      $count++;

    }

  }

return $count;

}

$count = arrayCounter($data);

echo 'Count: ' . $count;  //Using your data this will return "2".
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Nigel Ren Thank you for the link.  I should have tested this before I posted it..  I learned something new!